# FireBase Slugs for Unique URL

Tags: firebase

I have a database of `channels`:

```
-- "channels"
  -- -K2Pfj6eoAEnF-gI5
     -- "CNN"
     -- "Channel 1 description"
  -- -K2141fagdsa4nF-gI34
     -- "CNN"
     -- "Channel 2 description"
  -- -K2jdamaiefw4F-34Mid
     -- "Discovery Channel"
     -- "Channel 3 description"
```

I'm trying to create a readable url such as: `www.example.com/channels/cnn-2`

Is there functionality to generate a unique slug in Firebase?

#### Alternative?

Not sure if its good practice to reveal the `key` in the url, but is there anything wrong with a url like: `www.example.com/channels/-K2jdamaiefw4F-34Mid`

Comment: Firebase itself routinely uses the keys in its URLs. In fact, the above data is addressable as `https://<your-app>.firebaseio.com/channels/-K2jdamaiefw4F-34Mid`. So technically, these are completely valid URLs. Whether this is acceptable for your use-case, only you can decide.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think it's not good for SEO. Does Firebase have some function to generate unique readable slug from a text (eg, title text)?

Comment: I'm doing something similar. In my case it will look like http://domain.com/questions/??firebaseID??/question_slug.html

Comment: @Onichan did you come up with a solution to this 3 years later?

Comment: @GabLeRoux just generate a unique slug if you need readable urls.

Comment: So I guess I'd need some firebase function to make sure the slug is unique when saving